# VueJs and Vuex, how to attach v-model to dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, parent-child, vuex, state-management

I have a series of checkboxes generated by a database.  The database call isn't usually finished before the page loads.

This is part of my Vue.

folderList is a list of folders from the database, each has a key, and a doc.label for describing the checkbox and a doc.hash for using as a unique key.

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-if="foldersList!=null" v-for="folder in folderData">
            <Checkbox :id="folder.key" :name="folder.hash" label-position="right" v-model="searchTypeList[folder.hash]">{{ folder.doc.label }}</Checkbox>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
export default {
    name: 'Menu',
    components: {
        Checkbox,
        RouteButton
    },
    props: {
        foldersList: {type: Array, required: true}
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            searchListType: 'getSearchListType'
        }),
        searchTypeList: {
            get() {
                return this.searchTypeList;
            },
            set(newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
                //Vuex store commit
                this.$store.commit(Am.SET_SEARCH_TYPES, newValue);
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
            checkAllTypes: _.debounce(function (folderList){
            const initialList = {};
            folderList.forEach((folder) => {
                initialList[folder.hash] = true;
            });
            this.$store.commit(Am.SET_SEARCH_TYPES, initialList);
        }, 100)
    },
    mounted() {
        //hacky way of prefilling data after it loads
        this.$store.watch(
            (state) => {
                return this.foldersList;
            },
            this.checkAllTypes,
            {
                deep: false
            }
        );
    }
```

Checkbox is a custom component with a sliding style checkbox, it's v-model is like this

```
<template>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label :for="id" v-if="labelPosition==='left'">
            <slot></slot>
        </label>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" :name="name" :id="id" :disabled="isDisabled" v-bind:checked="checked" v-on:change="$emit('change',  $event.target.checked)"/>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
        <label :for="name" v-if="labelPosition==='right'">
            <slot></slot>
        </label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Checkbox',
        model: {
            prop: 'checked',
            event: 'change'
        },
        props: {
            id: {default: null, type: String},
            name: {required: true, type: String},
            isDisabled: {default: false, type: Boolean},
            checked: Boolean,
            labelPosition: {default: 'left', type: String},
            value: {required: false}
        }
    };
</script>
```

I verified checkbox is working by using a simple non dynamic v-model and without the loop.

I want to collect an array of checked values.

In my example above, I tried with this computed to try and link to vuex like I have with other fields, but the get counts as a mutation because it is adding properties to the object as it loops through.  I don't know how to solve this

Vuex:

```
const state = {        
    searchListType: {}
};

const getters = {
    getSearchListType: function (state) {
        return state.searchListType;
    }
};

const mutations = {
    [Am.SET_SEARCH_TYPES]: (state, types) => {
        state.searchListType = types;
    }
};
```

What is the correct way to link these up? I need the values in vuex so several sibling components can use the values and store them between page changes.

Also, what is the correct way to prefill the data? I assume I have a major structure problem here.  FolderList is async and can load at any point, however it doesn't typically change after the application has loaded.  It is populated by the parent, so the child just needs to wait for it to have data, and every time it changes, check off everything by default.

Thank you

Comment: Hello @Trevor! Just to clarify, you want the values that searchTypeListValues get() and set(newValue) to effect your vuex? The question isn't clicking on my end I apologize. Also do your values need to be present prior to mounting your app or can it occur afterwards?

Comment: Pass the full array to the component, and inside the custom component add a new method that change the needed entry inside the array, and emit back the full array

Comment: @GrandIQ Hi, I am hoping to get the object keys to be set to the values form the checkbox.  It already happens that way if I just use a straight `data` value according to the dev tools, but not when I try to use the get and set method.  So like this: {chk1: true, chk2: false}.  My only other idea was to leave it as a `data` and add a click event to each checkbox and use that as a trigger to call a commit in vuex with the values.

Comment: Best way to play with parent-child components using [ props ] and vuex would help you to mutation using $this.store method to maintain the state of the component @TrevorD

Comment: @saurabhkamble No issue with parent child here, and in my case, it's sibling to sibling to child to sibling to child, scary stuff, better with vuex.  I just need to know how to write the get and set functions.  The get works, but the set has me stumped.

Comment: I am starting to think it's because the sub object isn't watched.  I have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest using a change event and method instead of computed get & set, but when testing I found the v-model works ok without any additional code. Below is a rough approximation of your scenario.

Maybe something in the custom component interaction is causing your issue?

Ref [Customizing Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), did you use

```js
model: {
  prop: 'checked',
  event: 'change'
},
props: {
  checked: Boolean
},
```

in the Checkbox component?

---

```js
Vue.component('Checkbox', {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    checked: Boolean
  },
  template: `
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-bind:checked="checked"
      v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    >
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    folderData: [],
    searchTypeList: {}
  },
  created() {
    // Dynamic checkbox simulation
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.folderData = [
        { key: 1 },
        { key: 2 },
        { key: 3 },
      ]
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<ul>
  <li v-if="folderData != null" v-for="folder in folderData">
    <Checkbox :id="folder.key" :name="folder.key" 
      v-model="searchTypeList[folder.key]"></Checkbox>
  </li>
</ul>

{{searchTypeList}}

</div>
```

---

### Handling Vuex updates

I think the simplest way to handle updates to the store is to split `v-model` into `:checked` and `@change` properties. That way your control does not attempt to write back to the store directly, but still takes it's value from the store directly and reacts to store changes (both changes from an api call and from this component's `$store.commit()` calls).

This is the relevant guide [Vuex Form Handling](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html).

```
<ul>
  <li v-if="folderData != null" v-for="folder in folderData">
    <Checkbox :id="folder.key" :name="folder.key" 
      :checked="theList[folder.key]"
      @change="changeChecked(folder.key)"
      ></Checkbox>
  </li>
</ul>

...

computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    theList: 'getSearchListType'  // Standard getter with get() only
  }),
},
methods: {
  changeChecked(key) {
    this.$store.commit('updateChecked', key)  // Handle details in the mutation
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to change this into the get/set style and get it to work.  I don't yet know how to get the data to check the boxes after the database call is done, but if I stay stuck on that, I will ask another question.

Comment: Actually it almost works.  Referencing the object in the `get` throws a cannot mutate outside mutations error.  Presumably because the variable is being updating as it loops through.  How do I fix that?

Comment: The computed code you now have in the question is clearly wrong. It's getter returns itself and it's setter sets itself! The result is **vue.js:1743 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** in the console.

Comment: Sorry, it was a half edit.  I re-wrote the question.  I did get that error previously but fixed it.  What I am finding is that I have to cloneDeep() my get to make it stop complaining about mutating outside a mutation.  I can in theory know the folderList before this component loads, (the new prop probably loads twice, once empty, and once with values), how do I preload the values without having to clone?

Comment: I was thinking I could probably write this the exact opposite way too, and use a local data variable, and watch it to commit to vuex.  Seems equally bad though.

Comment: I am a still of the opinion that computed get/set is the wrong way to go. You are having to hack about and add extra code, and testing is going to be hard. There must be a simple pattern, Vue nearly always has one for every scenario. I'll have a look at it some more and append some code to my answer.

Comment: If you have a different way of getting the results into vuex I'm all for it

Comment: The way I'd do it is pretty much straight out of the Vue docs, I already added it to my answer. You may need to adapt it a little, but the basic premise is to update Vuex via a change event.